# How can I automount my hard disk partitions?

Tags: mount, automount

How can I auto-mount all my hard disk partitions?

Answer (score 4):

- Install [**pysdm**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pysdm) [image: Install pysdm]
- After installation it will be found under **System > Administration > Storage Device Manager**

[image]

- Select your partition from the partition list and click **Mount** and then **Apply**.
- Also for more information you can check this **[post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=217009)**.

Comment: thanks , but would this be enough for auto-mounting ??? I need the partions to be mounted at start up automatically

Comment: Yes that's enough..The partition will be mounted automatically at every boot..

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/fstab` is a configuration file that contains information of all the partitions and storage devices in your computer.

Make an entry there as below:

```
/dev/hdb1   /home   ext2    defaults    0 0
```

etc ... just change partition names ,  mount points  , Fstype.

Your partition will be mounted on next boot.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Search for "disks" from dash home. After you click the application called **Disks**, you should get a window something similar to this.

Click the Partition you would want and click the gear icon you see below it. Click **Edit mount options**. You will be presented with a window. Enable the automatic mount options by just sliding it to ON. Do this for all the partitions you want. And you are done! After next reboot, all the selected partitions will be mounted automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Download a utility called `pysdm`. When installed it should show up as **Storage Device Manager** under **System > Administration**. You can then set the drive to automatically mount from there.

What it actually does is alter a file on your system called `fstab`, which tells your system what filesystems to expect, but it's much easier to use the utility to edit it rather than doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic mounting could also done using `udisks` a command line tool. This is the modern replacement for gnome-mount. It's not gnome specific.

When you mount a disc normally with the file browser (nautilus etc) it mounts disks by interacting with udisks behind the scenes.

You can do the same thing on the command line with the udisks tool.

```
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdb1
```

The bit after `--mount` is the device name of the partition you want to mount. (/dev/something)

**Finding the device name of your Partition**

Open your partition in nautilus (this makes sure it's mounted)
type mount in a terminal. You should see a line with your disk name on it like:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/My-Happy-Disk type vfat ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a duplicate of this question, and have found an answer when looking for something else. In Kubuntu 16.04, you don't need a command line instruction or to install  software. Simply go to System Settngs > Removable Devices > Attached Devices and select Automount on Login. Good work by the developers!