# Internal hard disk mounting

Tags: boot, hard-drive, automount, fstab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AutoMounting hard disk partions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18229/automounting-hard-disk-partions)

I have a problem with mounting my internal hard disk in ubuntu.I have to manually mount it using /dev/mount/"name of disk" during boot only then it gets mounted. I want to set it boot automatically. How do I do that? Thanks