# How can I mount drives whilst booting

Tags: 14.04, mount, numlock

I have used 32-bit Kubuntu and am trying out 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity). By default Ubuntu when booting only mounts the partition on which it resides. I have several others, in cluding one which Ubuntu calls "37 GB Volume", alias /dev/sdb5 , on which Kubuntu and some data files reside. On the other systems on my computer, namely Windows XP and Kubuntu 12.04, all visible partitions are mounted on booting, and I believe I could achieve this by adding some code to a boot file; but I don't know the code and I don't know which file.
A related problem which XP can handle is to get the Numlock to come on while booting so that the number characters in my password are read properly.

Trivial problems, one may say, but I like to believe that anything Windows can do, Ubuntu can do better!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add the disks to your /etc/fstab or is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18229/automounting-hard-disk-partions

Answer (score 1):

You would add disks to your `/etc/fstab` file the same way as you would in Kubuntu, providing a line defining the device file, the file system, mount point, and other relevant options.  Kubuntu and Ubuntu are virtually the same with boot-time disk mounting, and use of the `/etc/fstab` file for defining at-boot mounting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't search long enough - it is indeed a duplicate. Thanks all for responses; fstab was the filename I forgot, but I'll have to experiment with the syntax.